# Proposition Question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to translate this into propositional symbols but (for me) it's so complicated. Can someone help me figure this out.

"If it rains then I will carry a sharp object and I will start laughing while everyone catches their breath; otherwise I will not play outside and pretend to be invisible."

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: Sounds like my plans for Friday night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all done with sentences and connectives: A sentence is usually  denoted by Capital letters like $A,B$, etc., the connectives are  or:=$ \lor$; and:=$\land$, and if-then:= $ \rightarrow$, and negation connective is $\lnot$ so that, e.g., If I go, then I will see a movie is transcribed as : say $A$ is " If I go" , and $B$ is , "I will see a movie" is represented as $ A\rightarrow B$. Then you can use additional connectives to make longer sentences. Does that help?

Comment: ahhh! I see! Now I get it! Thank you for answering my question! Thank you again! :)

Comment: Glad to help, Naomi :).